# Define requiredIf member in TypeScript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-proptypes

I have the following prop type definition:

```
const calendarEventPropType = PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    startDate: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date).isRequired,
    endDate: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date).isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(['stay']).isRequired,
    stay: requiredIf(stayPropType, props => props.type === 'stay'),
});
```

I am trying to convert this definition into TypeScript. I made the following:

```
interface ICalendarLayer {
    id: Number;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}

export interface ICalendarEvent extends ICalendarLayer {
    title: string;
    type: string;
    stay?: IStay;
}
```

But I want to be more specific. Means that if type equals "stay", stay member must contain IStay implementation. And otherwise, stay can be empty.
How can I define that as an interface in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Union type:

```
 interface IRegularEvent extends ICalendarLayer {
   title: string;
   type: "someother" | "type";
   // stay?: IStay; // not sure if you need that?
 }

 interface IStayEvent extends ICalendarLayer {
   type: "stay";
   stay: IStay;
 }

 export type ICalendarEvent = IRegularEvent | IStayEvent;
```

Comment: Can ICalendarEvent be an interface?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: You can easily extend it by combining more interfaces.

Comment: You used |. Your solution doesn't force me the title. title is mandatory (and I don't want to set it in each interface mentioned in ICalendarEvent.

Comment: It does. Both interfaces extend `IRegularEvent`.

Comment: IStayEvent extends from ICalendarLayer. And if it will extend from IRegularEvent, there will be duplication on "type" key. What will happen in such case?

Comment: Try it. Also I'm not sure why that would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

```js
interface ICalendarLayer {
  id: Number;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
}

export interface ICalendarEvent extends ICalendarLayer {
  title: string;
  type: string;
  stay?: boolean;
}

function ChildTest(props: ICalendarEvent) {
  const {endDate,id,startDate,stay,title,type} = props;
  return(<></>);
}

function ParentTest(params:any) {

  const [stay, setStay] = useState(false)
  const actionStay = () => {
    /* if stay control */
    setStay(!stay);
  }
  return(
    <>
    <ChildTest endDate={new Date()} startDate={new Date()} id={1} stay={stay} title="lorem" type="lorem" />
    <button onClick={actionStay}></button>
    </>
  );
```